# searchview in a fragment with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, searchview

I'm trying to implement a SearchView a fragment and using a navigation drawer, The app compiles, but the methods of OnQueryTextListener , OnActionExpandListener do nothing when i press the SearchView button.

XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/search1"
        android:visible="true"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnQueryTextListener, OnActionExpandListener {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    ActionBar actionBar;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    public TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    public ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,

                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }


    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MapFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opcion2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opcion3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opcion4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opcion5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opcion6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

       MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, this);

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    /**
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items

        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(newText + "hello");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
        android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "onMenuItemActionExpand");
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
        android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "onMenuItemActionCollapse");
        Toast.makeText(this,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

and my fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener  {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;
    public CameraUpdate mCamera;
    private Polyline line;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());




        setUpMap();

        return v;
    }

    public void setUpMap(){

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);



       }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                if (line.isVisible()) {
                    line.remove();
                }
            }
        });
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater){
        menu.clear();
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

    }



}
```

My objetive is to use the geocode of googlemaps in the SearchView , I have one months trying this. pls help